# Razor form helpers with a collection, how to name form elements correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, form-helpers

I have a page where a Manager registers, and during the restoration they can add up o 3 Users.

The User form is in a partial.

The view model has a collection of Users:

```
public class ManagerRegistrationViewModel
{
  public List<User> Users {get; set;}

  public ManagerRegistrationViewModel()
  {
      Users = new List<User>();
      Users.Add(new User(....));
      Users.Add(new User(....));
      Users.Add(new User(....));
  }
}

public ActionResult  ManagerRegistration()
{
   var vm = new ManagerRegistrationViewModel();

   return View("ManagerRegistration", vm);
}
```

ManagerRegistration.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div id="users">
    @{  Html.RenderPartial("_User", Model.Users[0]); }
    @{  Html.RenderPartial("_User", Model.Users[1]); }
    @{  Html.RenderPartial("_User", Model.Users[2]); }
</div>


}
```

My question is, in the partial, I am NOT currently using the Html helpers.

For example, and text input looks like:

```
<input type=text name="Users[0].Name" />
```

But I want to use the Html helpers for textboxes and dropdown lists etc. because for Edit pages it sets the current value/state of the form element.

**How can I use Html helpers in this scenerio?**

The form elements have to be named like:

```
Users[x].Property
```

I would ideally like to somehow keep using the strongly typed way like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these scenarios, you should be using `EditorTemplates` **not** partial views, otherwise you won't get any proper naming on your fields.

So you'd have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Users[0])
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Users[1])
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Users[2])
```

Or more appropriately, in a `for` loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Users[i])  
}
```

Comment: can you use EditorFor with dropdowns?

Comment: I can be just one line of code -  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Users)` which will correctly generate the html for all items in the collection.